# python fit_transform index error for large dataset

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, text-classification

I am doing text classification on sentiment analysis, where I have a large training set and test set

```
test_data_df.shape (46346, 2)  train_data_df.shape  (69518, 2)
```

The first column of train_data_df is label, which has value 1 if email is a personal attack and 0 if not. The second column of train_data_df is comment, which is the email content. However, when I try to use

```
fit_transform
```

to transform corpus into feature vectors, I got

```
 corpus_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(train.comment.tolist() + 
 test.comment.tolist())
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 839, in fit_transform
 self.fixed_vocabulary_)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 762, in _count_vocab
 for feature in analyze(doc):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/sklearn/feature_extraction/text.py", line 241, in <lambda>
 tokenize(preprocess(self.decode(doc))), stop_words)
 File "assignment3.py", line 23, in tokenize
 stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
 File "assignment3.py", line 14, in stem_tokens
 stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 665, in stem
 stem = self._step1b(stem)
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 376, in _step1b
 lambda stem: (self._measure(stem) == 1 and
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site- 
 packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 258, in _apply_rule_list
 if suffix == '*d' and self._ends_double_consonant(word):
 File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/lib/python3.5/site-
 packages/nltk/stem/porter.py", line 214, in _ends_double_consonant
 word[-1] == word[-2] and
 IndexError: string index out of range
```

Below is my code, which I learnt from https://www.codementor.io/jadianes/data-science-python-r-sentiment-classification-machine-learning-du107otfg. Could anyone help me to point out where I might possibly went wrong? Thank you very much!

```
import numpy as np 
import re, nltk
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer        
from nltk.stem.porter import PorterStemmer
test_data_df = pd.read_csv('test.tsv', delimiter="\t", quoting=3)
train_data_df = pd.read_csv('train.tsv', delimiter="\t", quoting=3)
stemmer = PorterStemmer()
def stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer):
    stemmed = []
    for item in tokens:
        stemmed.append(stemmer.stem(item))
    return stemmed

def tokenize(comment):
    comment = re.sub("[^a-zA-Z]", " ", comment)
    tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(comment)
    stems = stem_tokens(tokens, stemmer)
    return stems

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(
    analyzer = 'word',
    tokenizer = tokenize,
    lowercase = True,
    stop_words = 'english',
    max_features = 200
)
corpus_data_features = 
vectorizer.fit_transform(train_data_df.comment.tolist() +  test_data_df.comment.tolist())
```

The last line of code is where problem comes from. Thank you!

Comment: You should always post the complete stack trace of error. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @VivekKumar Sorry about this, I just posted complete stack of error.